# How to Authenticate User using Laravel Api routes and Vue 2 Js and Vue Router

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, vue-router, axios

My goal is that laravel has an implemented Authorization Provider for us

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

so  I want to authenticate my users by using that by an API and set it back to my Vue Router

and authorize the users

How can i implement it?

Im always getting an error on authentication

im using axios as my HTTP provider

Here is the app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)

Vue.use(VueRouter);

axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm.vue';

import RegisterForm from './components/RegisterForm.vue';

Vue.component('login-form',LoginForm)

Vue.component('register-form',RegisterForm)
// Directives

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: require('./pages/Index.vue') },
  { path: '/admin/users', component: require('./pages/admin/Users.vue') },

  { path: '/user/:id', component: require('./pages/user/Dashboard.vue'),
    children: [
      // UserHome will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
      // when /user/:id is matched
      { path: '', component: require('./pages/user/Index.vue')},

      // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
      // when /user/:id/posts is matched
      { path: 'settings', component: { template: '<div>Settings</div>' } },
    ]
  },

  { path: '/manager/:id', component: require('./pages/user/Dashboard.vue'),
    children: [
      // UserHome will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
      // when /user/:id is matched
      { path: '', component: require('./pages/user/Index.vue')},

      // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
      // when /user/:id/posts is matched
      { path: 'settings', component: require('./pages/user/Settings.vue') },
    ]
  },
  { path: '/store/:id', component: require('./pages/user/Dashboard.vue'),
    children: [
      // UserHome will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
      // when /user/:id is matched
      { path: '', component: require('./pages/user/Index.vue')},

      // UserPosts will be rendered inside User's <router-view>
      // when /user/:id/posts is matched
      { path: 'settings', component: { template: '<div>Settings</div>' } },
    ]
  },
  { path: '/*', component: require('./pages/404.vue') },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: `<div id="#app">
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>`,

})
```

Here is the a Login form component

```
<template>
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent='submitForm'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" v-model="login.email" placeholder="Email"> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" v-model="login.password" placeholder="Password"> 
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block"> Login </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                errors: [],
                login: {
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    _token: window.Laravel.csrfToken

                }
            }
        },

        methods: {
            submitForm() {
                this.axios.post('/login',this.login)
                    .then(response => {

                    })
                    .catch(response => {
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

this is my Laravel API

in api.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

Route::get('/auth',function() {
   return Auth::user(); 
});
Route::resource('/users','UserController');

Route::resource('/stores','StoreController');

Route::resource('/items','ItemController');

Route::resource('/transactions','StoreController');

Route::resource('/managers','ManagerController');

Route::resource('/employees','EmployeeController');

Route::resource('/customers','CustomerController');

Route::resource('/tags','TagController');

});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

So my BIG PROBLEM here is the authentication using vue i'm used to authentication in blade templates and laravel routes but not on vue

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Updated it please help

Comment: You claimed you get an error - what error do you get? And where and when do you get it?

Comment: the ERROR is always response of 302 

ive modified the verifycsrfmiddleware to return true because im always getting token mismatch error
   
ive done this to the verifycsrfmiddleware 

said by some guy

Comment: You shouldn't disable csrf just to make it work - it's part of the security. I'm not sure why you use axios instead of vue resource - you would find easy examples on how to provide the csrf token in every request. However, I think you receive an error response don't you? Can you post it?

Comment: I've made a new question i figured out what you said
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635012/csrf-token-duplication-on-vue-router-laravel-5-3-vue-2-js
so this question maybe clear to you?

Please help